# Spring Data or plain JPA with dynamic calculated column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jdbctemplate, criteria-api

guys.
I have some shop objects, which have coordinates (latitude and longitude). I want to expose the distance between user current location and shop. The problem is that this field is dynamic and I cannot represent the value with regular field in the Shop entity. If I put something like this

```
@Transient
private BigDecimal distance;
```

Spring Data cannot map this property, because it is ignored.
I can make it with jdbcTemplate and raw queries but it is too much coding :)

SO basically, my questions is how to map addition column which is calculated dynamically to the JPA entity which don't have persisted property

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

1) [@PostLoad](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks-example) annotation to make custom calculation of your transient property on application level:

```
@PostLoad
public void calculateDistance() {
    this.distance = ...;
}
```

2) [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula) annotation to make calculation on database level (using your native SQL dialect):

```
@Formula(value = "...") // your calculation here in native SQL
private BigDecimal distance;
```

(`@Transient` annotation must be excluded in this case.)

Comment: Can I use @Formula with preparedStatemens ?

Comment: @Rostislav No. `@Formula` works on _database level_ - it is part of native sql statement (see links I provided)

Comment: Yes, i saw it.. So in this case nothing from the mentioned methods won't work... The query has prepared statements and self object field(column) references. I guess I should use jdbcTemplate ...

Comment: @Rostislav you question was: "how to map addition column which is calculated dynamically to the JPA entity which don't have persisted property?" - I answered on it.

Comment: You are right my friend. I will mark your answer as solution